# Does this hold: $\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}-r\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}=-mr^{m+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m}r^{n}$

Tags: summation

$\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}-r\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}=-mr^{m+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m}r^{n}$  ,where $n,m$ are integers.

Is it true?

If yes how to show it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}-r\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n+1} \\ 
 &=  r + \sum_{n=2}^{m}nr^{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{m}(n-1)r^{n} - m r^{m+1} \\ 
 &= r + \sum_{n=2}^m (n - (n-1))r^n - mr^{m+1}\\ 
 &= r + \sum_{n=2}^m r^n- mr^{m+1}\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^m r^n- mr^{m+1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. I think in the second step it should be $-mr^{m+1}$ instead of $-mr^{m+2}$.

Comment: @Sush thanks for correction ... i'll edit it.